# Laravel store latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, latitude-longitude

I'm storing latitude and longitude and the problem I'm having is when it is being stored it gets rounded up, which isn't what I want. Otherwise those field values become incorrect when using the latitude and longitude on the map.

This is what I'm using:

```
$table->decimal('lat', 10, 8)->nullable();
$table->decimal('lng', 11, 8)->nullable();
```

this value -40.95560269999999 gets turned into this -40.9556027000 when I just want -40.9556026999

Comment: have you tried using double?

Comment: For me, I used `string` length 25. It's okay for me because you don't need to calculate on it, just display it =))

Comment: @SangNguyen that's exactly what Im going to do

Comment: Your data type simply hasn't enough decimals.

Comment: Use a mutator to modify the latitude/longitude before saving to database.

Comment: Consider whether you need such ridiculously precise coordinates.  You can use this XKCD comic for reference. https://xkcd.com/2170/

You are squarely within the "Check out this specific grain of sand" part of the chart.

Answer (score 14):

Use ***double*** in your migrations instead of decimals, see below

```
$table->double('lat')->nullable();
$table->double('lng')->nullable();
```

Comment: You can as well specify the decimal part and whole number part as in your question as below; ```$table->double('lat', 10,8)->nullable();
$table->double('lng', 11,8)->nullable();```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to use double in your migrations instead of decimals, is see below:

```
$table->decimal('long', 10, 7)->nullable();
$table->decimal('lat', 10, 7)->nullable();
```

Answer (score -3):

your field's data type might be not decimal, make it sure that your field of lat long is decimal too